# Possible to upgrade RAM to 16 GB for mac mini mid 2011?

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-mini

Does anyone has experience with upgrading a mac mini mid 2011 to 16 GB RAM?

I know the official doc says the max is 8 GB RAM, but there are articles on the internet which claim it is possible.

The official doc: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202283
Article which claims it is possible: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3859325

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.5-mid-2011-specs.html) says it will take 16 - & they're pretty much always right in these things.

The machines from that time didn't have official 8GB RAM stick support, as they were pretty new at the time & I guess untested; but it later turned out all those older machines would take 8s, even though only qualified for 4s.

I've had several machines over the years with double the officially-supported RAM.

Comment: anybody suggestions which ram and where to buy it?

Comment: the usual suspects would be Crucial, Kingston, maybe Corsair - or you could go the eBay route, which I've had luck with many times; less guarantee, but the dealers who trade in this stuff are usually smart enough to know which machines it will fit & which it won't.

Comment: @Tetsujin From my experience, a site called [Other World Computing](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/apple/memory/) has great Mac parts. One should compare their prices against Crucial and the others, as sometimes OWC is the most inexpensive of them all. Another thing I'd like to add is don't go to Best Buy to by Mac RAM.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 - the only problem with OWC is they're traditionally US-only [they have a very recent UK presence, but they're not global] My 'usual suspects' have, if not global, at least 'heavy western hemisphere presence'